# Best way to suggest enabling cross-site cookies with Brave

Tags: browser, authentication, cookies

For technical reasons (OIDC library uses CORS requests to renew API access tokens), our application requires that when using the Brave browser, the security shields built into Brave be either disabled or cross-site cookies enabled.

Any ideas or suggestions on the best way to inform the user of this?

During the login process, we could just have some italic text for this, but would be easily ignored.

I was envisioning perhaps having the Brave logo somewhere in the app, perhaps in the footer with a tooltip / overlay and a popup on click that clarified that the authentication session will not renew past 6 minutes without cross-site cookies enabled and a description of how to enable this.

Any other ideas or thoughts on the best ways to convey this to our users as painlessly as possible?

Thanks, really appreciate any and all suggestions!

Comment: Also wasn't sure if there would be any intellectual property issues with using the Brave logo for this, but would be eye catching for anybody using that browser...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably best thing you can do is fix the root cause (that "technical reasons"). Your application should not be worse than other sites of the Internet.

Until you resolve your CORS issue, you can help your users to set the needed settings. You know your target browser, so make a small screenshot of its Settings page displaying what exactly you want to be changed.